# Get Meta Tags from External site

Tags: php, html, metadata, meta-tags

I want to get `news_keywords` from this `meta`:

```
 <meta name="news_keywords" content="bla, bla, bla tag">
 <meta property="og:title" content="title example">
```

i try with simple code and doesn't work

```
 $tags = get_meta_tags($link);
 echo $tags['news_keywords'];
```

Comment: It works for me, maybe the link variable is the issue.

Comment: I have a problem in the url, I tried with another link is work

Answer (score 1):

That's a minor mistake. Change it to:

```
echo $tags['news_keywords'];
```

Outputs:

```
bla, bla, bla tag
```

Comment: I already set $tags['news_keywords']; in the code but its not working

Comment: @AdnenChouibiChouibi: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled? You can check it with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: I have a problem in the url, I tried with another link is work

Answer (score -1):

You are echo-ing a wrong tag, try echo `$tags['news_keywords']` not `$tag['news_keywords']`

Comment: I have a problem in the url, I tried with another link is work